# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.view.ViewPager" on path

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, androidx

I just migrated my project to androidx and i am getting an inflation error for inflating viewpager component...I replaced android.support.v4.view.ViewPager with androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

This my **xml** file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:padding="@dimen/_1dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/banner_border_color">

      <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/vp_slider"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/_140dp"
           android:background="@drawable/thumb_new_background" />

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="bottom">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tv_banner_view_more"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/drawable_btn_curved"
                   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_6dp"
                   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8dp"
                   android:paddingRight="@dimen/_8dp"
                   android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6dp"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                   android:text="@string/text_view_more"
                   android:textColor="@color/c_white"
                   android:textSize="@dimen/_8sp" />

     </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**The Error** i'm getting :

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #329: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.core.view.ViewPager
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.core.view.ViewPager
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.view.ViewPager" on path: DexPathList[
```

Comment: look like the error is in different xml file, search whole your project about `androidx.core.view.ViewPager`. if you don't find any place use `androidx.core.view.ViewPager`, then just need to clean project

Comment: post your app `build.gradle` file. Hope you have not included it in any `aar library`

Comment: Have u added below `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06' dependencies in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @SantanuSur yes my project have external aar file

Comment: @NileshRathod no this dependency not added

Comment: @dev_swat you need to add that `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to below `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0
```

Comment: alpha08 is lattes avilable or need to stick with 06?

Comment: @dev_swat it's your choice if you want to use `alpha08` or `alpha06` I'm currently using `alpha06`

Comment: app still crashing after  adding dependency :(

Comment: @dev_swat can u share latest crash log with question after adding these dependencies

Answer (score 37):

I figure out problem,
When we merger to androidx then android studio convert viewpager, swipe to refresh layout and some other views to **androidx.core** for example viewpager its looks like **androidx.core.view.ViewPager** but correct is **androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager** please check in your xml layouts and see there is right component is added or not if there is androidx.core then check for right one and replace it.
And also import dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08
```

Comment: @dev_swat Thanks a ton. for the catch in the XML layout

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below dependencies in your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Invalidate caches and restart

Go to **File** > **Invalidate caches/Restart** > ** Invalidate

Then rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade build.gradle and gradle wrapper version

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
     distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```